# Debugging on Windows Phone 7 emulator causes internet connectivity to be lost

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am currently trying to develop a Windows Phone 7 app and corresponding REST Web API project. I have been encountering problems with the emulator talking to the API. After testing with JQuery and Fiddler I came to find that the emulator is losing internet connectivity with my system.

I am wondering if anyone else has seen this issue and can recommend something. At this moment the only fix I have been able to find is to restart my entire machine which is not something that makes development either fun or efficient.  If anyone can recommend anything I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler creates a proxy when running. Gotta reset the Internet Options of the host machine and it usually goes back to working